# WCF with basic authentification (Remote Server returned an error: 404 Not found)

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, basic-authentication

I am trying to access my wcf (http protocol using port 26880) service externally (deployed on IIS) after setting it up with a Basic Authentication Module, but it throws the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

What I have tried so far:

1. Removed the basic authentication and checked that the service can be accessed both internally and externally and that works.
2. Checked that the service actually receives the header authorization and the user is logged in.(This works)
3. Added the following line in my web.config file:
   `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` 
   after adding my BasicAuthenticationModule and still no luck.
4. Went in IIS and made sure that BasicAuthentication is enabled.
5. Enabled trace logging and apparently I cannot see any errors besides the fact that it looks at this address:  `http://localhost/ResponseService` 
   when in fact it should be `http://localhost:26880/ResponseService`

I have googled and tried every possible solution that I found related to my error and no results so far.

This is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" enable="true" executionTimeout="60000"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="dcs_response_handler.ResponseService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://'external ip':26880/DcsResponse/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="webHttpBinding" contract="dcs_response_handler.IResponseService" binding="webHttpBinding" address="" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"/>
        <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webBehavior">
              <webHttp />
          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding"
                 transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="BasicAuthenticationModule"/>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
      <add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" type="dcs_response_handler.BasicAuthenticationModule" preCondition=""/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="false"/>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
    </authentication>
          <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="32000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="Error.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

And my `BasicAuthenticationModule` along with `BasicAuthenticationProvider` (source [Custom Basic Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication/)):

```
public class BasicAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest
        += new EventHandler(context_AuthenticateRequest);
    }

    void context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (!BasicAuthenticationProvider.Authenticate(application.Context))
        {
            application.Context.Response.Status = "401 Unauthorized";
            application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            application.Context.Response.AddHeader("WWW - Authenticate", "Basic");
            application.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}


public class BasicAuthenticationProvider
{
    public static bool Authenticate(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Authorization"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        IPrincipal principal;
        if (TryGetPrincipal(authHeader, out principal))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string authHeader, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        var creds = ParseAuthHeader(authHeader);

        if (creds != null && TryGetPrincipal(creds, out principal))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            principal = null;
            return false;
        }
    }


    private static string[] ParseAuthHeader(string authHeader)
    {
        if (
            authHeader == null ||
            authHeader.Length == 0 ||
            !authHeader.StartsWith("Basic")
        )
        {
            return null;
        }

        string base64Credentials = authHeader.Substring(6);
        string[] credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
              Convert.FromBase64String(base64Credentials)
        ).Split(new char[] { ':' });

        if (credentials.Length != 2 ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0]) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[1])
        )
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Okay this is the credentials
        return credentials;
    }

    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string[] creds, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (ValidateLogin.IsLoginValid(new System.Net.NetworkCredential(creds[0], creds[1])))
        {
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(
               new GenericIdentity(creds[0]),
               new string[] { "Administrator", "Users" }
            );
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            principal = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my client:

```
public static void ServiceClientTest()
{
    HttpWebRequest req = null;
    HttpWebResponse resp = null;
    string SampleXml = string.Empty;

    string baseAddress = "http://'external ip':26880/DcsResponse/XMLGate/inbound?System=84771500";
    try
    {
        string strResult = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Alin\Desktop\testingXml.xml"))
        {
            SampleXml = readFile.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string postData = SampleXml.ToString();
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("alin" + ":" + "Dcs1234"));


        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseAddress);
        webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);

        webrequest.Method = "POST";

        webrequest.ContentType = "text/xml"; 
        webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();   
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

        if (webresponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream stream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web exception :" + webEx.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception :" + ex.Message);
    }           
}
```

Based on the error I am getting I'm assuming that it can't find a file or my web.config is not setup properly? Any new ideas?

Comment: Eventually got it to work by changing the binding from BasicHttpBinding to WebHttpBinding and change the security mode from Transport to None (Updated the web.config).

Comment: I am still unsure why I was getting the the 404 Not found error but I started by removing the BasicAuthorizationModule and re-test the service and make sure that I can access it both internally and externally. Afterwards I've implemented the webHttpBinding and setup the security mode to None which pretty much made everything to work. Now I have a full functioning WCF service with Basic Authentication. Hope this will help someone that is the same situation i was.